# Wildcard filename in schema.ini?

Tags: .net

Was wondering if there was a way to put a wildcard in the schema.ini for example
[*.txt]
FMT=TabDelimited

I've got an app that is imported tab delimited files and the only place I can seem to get the FMT="TabDelimited" is in the schema.ini (doesn't work in the connection string for some reason), but I will have no idea what the filenames are other than the txt extension.

BTW I'm connecting using an OdbcConnection and the Microsoft Text Driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I could potentially rename the file temporarily to match whatever I decide to put in the schema.ini or potentially modify the schema.ini on the fly and put the correct filename in there, but I'd love to do know if there was a better way.

Comment: I went ahead with modifying the schema.ini on the fly for each file.

Answer (score 0):

A single schema.ini file can contain multiple
[fileName.txt] entries and format 
descriptions, (for all the files in the 
Directory), so you might consider creating the .ini
file dynamically from the directory file names.